# Как передать статус ответа после перезагрузки страницы? PHP

Tags: php

Имеется участок кода, который позволяет выполнить действие (отправить форму), и после успешной или не успешной отправки выводит статус ответа `echo error($ln['error_email']);`, но когда обновляешь страницу происходит повторная отправка ранее отправленной информации, решил проблему через редирект, но статус ответа после редиректа немогу отправить, как это сделать правильно? (без передачи в $_GET)

Answer (score 1):

1. Не отправлять редирект, если есть ошибки

   ```
    if($ln['error_email']){
        echo error($ln['error_email']);
    }else{
        header('location') ;
    }
   ```

Если страница будет обновлена, форма отправится повторно, но с выводом ошибки, или редирект, если ошибок нету.

Или
2. Записать статус ответа в сессию или куки

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['err'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['err'];
} 
$_SESSION['err'] = $ln['error_email'];
```

Или
3. Отправлять форму  AJAX-запросом